# why does tail -F -n 1 myfile.txt print .all. the contents of myfile as it gets updated?

Tags: terminal, tail

What I'm trying to do is really simple - I want to monitor a file and print its last line to the screen as the file gets updated. From what I know,

```
tail -F -n 1 myfile.txt
```

should do exactly that. However, I get strange behaviour: With the "original" myfile.txt, the command works fine and only the last line is printed to the screen. However, as soon as I alter myfile.txt by appending new lines of text, the entire contents of myfile.txt are printed - rather than just the very last line.

I have never used tail before and I might just be getting something terribly wrong here, but surely that's not the expected behaviour? I purposefully use the -F flag so I can manually alter myfile.txt - could that be the reason for it not working?

Help is very much appreciated...
Thanks so, so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's the way it's *meant* to work, `-n 1` is the *initial* behaviour, printing only the last line, but `-F` follows the file beyond that point, and states quite clearly:

> output appended data as the file grows;

In other words, it outputs *all* the appended data that's gone to the file.

If you examine the [source code](http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/src/tail.c), you'll notice the `main()` function first processes the `-n` option and, only at the end, does it call `tail_forever()`, in which there is no mention of the argument supplied with `-n`.

If you execute:

```
( echo 1; echo 2; echo 3 ) >qq
```

in one window then start up a tail in another:

```
tail -F -n 1
```

you should get only the line with 3.

If you then return to the original window and execute:

```
( echo 4; echo 5; echo 6 ) >>qq
```

your second window should just output the new lines (and all three of them).

If your second window gives you *all six* of the lines, it's broken.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to be annoying, but `output appended data` sounds to me as if it should, indeed, only output the _new_ lines, rather than the entire content of the file (including those lines that were there in the first place)?

Comment: @yay: yes, and that's what it does, at least for me. See the update for a test case for you to run.